# Proxmox internal network configuration

Tags: linux-networking, cloud-computing, proxmox

We have several servers (with one nic) staying in one rack in hetzner. Proxmox is installed on each one, and they are combined in proxmox cluster. The goal is to create network, between virtual machines on this servers, so that vm's located on one host could see vm's located on another host. What is the proper way to do this?